# SELECT MIN() and MAX() based in two different conditions for each of them

Tags: sql

In these queries

```
SELECT MIN(age) 
FROM ages 
WHERE id = 5 AND birth = 12;

SELECT MAX(age) 
FROM ages 
WHERE id = 5 AND birth = 65;
```

Is it possible to merge them both into a single query, only different in `birth`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN birth = 12 THEN age END)
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN birth = 65 THEN age END)
FROM ages 
WHERE id = 5
```

Comment: I think this query will perform full table scan.

Comment: @Naveed   this query scan only for id = 5 not full scan